# forgot wireless password

Tags: windows-xp, security, wireless-networking, passwords

If you have a laptop running XP that is able to connect to a wireless network fine, but you don't know the password it's using, is there any way to find it out so that a second laptop can also connect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run [Nirsoft's Wireless KeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) on the laptop that can connect.

Failing that, connect with a cable, and try to connect to the router's interface (your default gateway address, often 192.168.0.1, check the manual), and try to login with the default passwords (google or check the manual).

Comment: You may be able to connect to the router's management interface via the wireless. Default username/passwords are usually "admin/password", "admin/admin" or "admin/<blank>"